# MySQL vs PostgreSQL vs SQLite для высоконагруженных сайта на PHP?

Tags: highload, sqlite, php, postgresql, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую БД выбрать(MySQL vs PostgreSQL vs SQLite) для высокоангруженного сайта на PHP в котором будет примерно 300 000 статей, и 50 000-60 000 заходов на сайт в день?

Спасибо!

Comment: Не SQLite однозначно.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, что стоит за одним "заходом". Сколько  запросов к базе делает каждый заход ? С какой интенсивностью ?

Если считать в среднем, то получится примерно 2 захода в секунду. IMHO величина для современной техники небольшая.

Comment: avp, но ведь пользователи не будут заходить по очереди. Будет днём - пик, а ночью простой.

Comment: Я 60000 на 10 (часов) делил. Ну, а если не 2 а 20 заходов в секунду - это решительно изменит картину ?

Вы тесты напишите, померьте производительность с **любой** (какая есть под рукой) базой.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну для больших проектов SQLite точно не стоит выбирать. А что касается MySQL и PostgreSQL, то это скорее зависит от собственных предпочтений и кривизны рук)) Несколько интересных ссылок:

- [PostgreSQL vs MySQL: есть тесты на больших таблицах?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/6675/)
- [PostgreSQL vs MySQL vs ...](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=28873)
- [MySQL vs PostgreSQL](http://valera.ws/2007.09.04~postgresql-vs-mysql/)

Comment: "Ну для больших проектов SQLite точно не стоит выбирать" - я бы сказал что его не стоит выбирать если база многопользовательская. Для монопользовательской однопоточной базы sqlite и для больших проектов хорошь - во всяком случае скоростью и объёмами. Надо понимать что SQLite это локальная, файловая база данных и ничего больше.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL выглядит более предпочтительнее по ряду причин:

1. Более "умный" планировщик запросов.
2. Возможность использования нескольких индексов на одной таблице (MySQL может использовать только один индекс на одну таблицу).
3. Функциональные индексы (индексы по выражению, а не по данным из столбца).

Answer (score 0):

Для высоких нагрузок - postgresql
Кроме того, что тут написали

```
1)Много типов индексов
функциональные, частичные;
Триграмные индексы для запросов к тексту WHERE LIKE '%any%template%'(кому 
надо искать по шаблону, например в табличке с 10-20 миллионов строк - 
оценят),запросов,неточный поиск итд;
Если надо - крутой полнотекст(кому надо было его использовать на транзакциях
 в  mysql -  оценят);
География;
индексация внутренней структуры jsonb для быстрого поиска;
методы индексирования gist\gin\btree а будут и ещё 
2) полно всяких фишек для генерации отчётов на стороне SQL
   рекурсивные и обычные табличные выражения;
   аналитические функции;
   pivot(дополнение),unnest,generate_series,rollup и т.п.;
3)Очень много типов и крутые возможности контроля целостности по ним,
  например, задача бронирования номеров\мест на диапазон дат решается в лоб
  даже без триггеров и хранимок, чисто констрейнами.
4)фишки для скорости и для интерактива
   функционал для организации очередей массового обслуживания;
   система очень быстрых сообщений между клиентами;
   unlogged таблицы ;
   матвьюхи
5) средства для отказоустойчивости
     репликация из коробки;
     различные методы резервного копирования;
     мониторинг;
6)удобства для проггера 
   богатый pl\pgsql;
   можно писать на чём хочешь, хоть на plr,питоне и джаваскрипте;
   чеки,ключи;
   можно писать запросы не на sql, а прямо на языке хранимок, какой выберешь.
```